# VBA workbook out of range - subscript error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a

> subscript out of range

error when im passing an array and a workbook into this function. Can anyone see what's wrong with it?

--Update--

```
Private Function PasteFunction(cd As Variant, wk As Workbook) As Boolean

Dim bool As Boolean, row As Integer, col As Integer
bool = False
col = 1
row = 3


Do While bool = False
MsgBox row
MsgBox col
    If IsEmpty(wk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col)) = True Then
        For col = 1 To 81
            wk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col) = cd(col)
        Next col
        bool = True

    Else
        row = row + 1
    End If
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: `row` is definitely a BAD variable name in Excel ! And row and col should be `Long`, never `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

This line produces the error:

```
If IsEmpty(wk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(col & row)) = True Then
```

`Range (col&row)` returns something like `Range(1223)` and excel awaits values like `Range("A12:A53")`.

Judging on your code, the logic should be like this:

`Cells(row, col)` instead of `Range(col & row)`.

Comment: I updated the line to
`If IsEmpty(wk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col).Value) = True Then`
Still getting the same error

Comment: What is `Tracher`? Is it the worksheet? Can you try to remove the `.Value`?

Comment: I removed the .value and still getting the same error

Comment: @Jarvey -  Try writing `debug.print row` and `debug.print col` before this line. Probably one of them is 0.

Comment: debug.print row/col didn't work but I used MsgBox row & MsgBox col. It showed me the value of 5 for row and 1 for col

Comment: @Jarvey -  Can you post the exact code that you are using?

Comment: `Private Function PasteFunction(cd As Variant, wk As Workbook) As Boolean


    Dim bool As Boolean, row As Integer, col As Integer

    bool = False

    col = 1

    row = 3



    Do While bool = False

    MsgBox row

    MsgBox col

        If IsEmpty(wk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col)) = True Then

            For col = 1 To 81

                wk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col) = cd(col)

            Next col

            bool = True

            
        Else

            row = row + 1

        End If

    Loop


End Function`

Comment: @Jarvey - write `msgbox wk.Name` and check what is it.

Comment: that works - it gives me the right workbook name. I think maybe there's something wrong with my array that I'm trying to pass in.

Comment: @Jarvey - where are you getting the error? Write `MsgBox Ubound(cd)` and if it is more than 81 you are in trouble. Actually, because of this thing here - `Do While bool = False` your array may go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

subscript out of range error could be caused either due to incorrect reference to workbook or sheet reference or because your array cd is shorter than 81 items. How are you calling your function. can you post your function call. The workbook path may be incorrect also check for spelling mistakes

Answer (score 0):

If cd has 81 elements then they run from cd(0) to cd(80)
If you want to put them into columns 1 to 81 you need

```
   For col = 1 To 81
        wk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col) = cd(col-1)
    Next col
```